# SLOT rejected(), accepted() in QMainWindow

Tags: qt

I am a newbie in Qt-programming. I have read a book about GUI-programming with Qt. I have an trouble in creating a dialog. Here is sample code:

// gotocell.h

```
#ifndef GOTOCELL_H
#define GOTOCELL_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "ui_gotocell.h"

class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GoToCellDialog (QWidget *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
};

#endif // GOTOCELL_H
```

// gotocell.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "gotocell.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog (QWidget *parent):
    QDialog (parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    QRegExp regExp ("[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]{0,2}");
    lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regExp, this));

    connect (okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect (cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}

void GoToCellDialog::on_lineEdit_textChanged()
{
     okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "gotocell.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GoToCellDialog *dialog = new GoToCellDialog;
    dialog->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

but when I compiled, there is an error: `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'GoToCellDialog* const' to 'QMainWindow*'`at `setupUi()` function. I think because the designer in Qt Creator created a QMainWindow, not a QDialog. So I changed GoToCellDialog class to QMainWindow. But there is no slots whose name is "accepted", "rejected" in QMainWindow. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can select to create a QDialog instead of QMainWindow when creating a form. If you want to use the same widget in both a main window and in a dialog, design a QWidget and embed that in the main window and dialog, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a Dialog as main window you have two choices:
 1. make the whole main window QDialog based
 2. design the Dialog separately and set it as the main windows central Widget (QMainWindow->setCentralWidget()).

In both cases you still have the problem what semantics you give to the OK and Cancel buttons. Generally it may be a better idea to consider what the main window of the application should contain, and design the dialogs later.